# default -o flag with g++/cang++ in VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++, clang++, flags

How can I edit the default -o flag in VSCode? I want my executable to end with .out but if I set the -o flag in preferences>Cpp flags I get an error because VSCode keeps the old -o flag. Now VSCode creates a directory "output" where the executable is stored. I Just want to have the .out file in the same directory like the code.

After compile-run "ask wird ausgeführt: g++ rect.cpp -o /Users/steffenrein/Documents/Code/Programmierparadigmen/lecture/03_exercises/sose23/s00/output/rect -std=c++17 -Wpedantic -Wall -Wextra -g3 " ist shown in the Terminal. But in my Preferences only "-Wall -Wextra -g3 -std=c++17" is set.

if I compile with g++ in the Terminal I get an error because g++ isn't using c++17 although I set it as the standard in my Preferences. But thats another problem I think

I would be really thankful if someone could help me because this is getting on my nerves although compiling and executing works

I thought VSCode would remove the default -o Flag if I set a different one in user- or workspace settings

Comment: First of all, please note that despite what you might have been told, VSCode isn't really an IDE, and it's not very beginner friendly.Secondly, have you read [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs)? Especially the C++ section which have pretty good documentation to get started with C++ in VSCode for the most common platforms.

Comment: Yes I really need to get a closer look on the documentation. BTW the error doesn't appear anymore. So now I get two executables by some reason...

Comment: how are you performing the build? build task? If so, show your tasks.json. Code Runner extension?